# Angular Repeat Conditionally Include in Dom

Tags: angularjs

I am in an ng-repeat. How do I conditionally add some html in the loop. So far, I have the following code:

```
<div ng-show="showCondition">
    <div>
         ...
         <input name="bla[{{obj.value}}].Id type="Text" /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

That certainly hides the html. But I still end up with inputs sending stuff to the server for iterations where I don't want the input to even exist.

I can't use ng-include, because the html is in the same file, in the loop.

How can I just say, "if true, render the following html during this iteration of the loop"?

Thanks

Comment: `ng-if` controls rendering, `ng-show` controls visibility.  That being said, any time I see expressions inside bracket notation like this, I wonder if the data is structured correctly to begin with.

Comment: @Claies you got in first, so if you formalize your suggestion in an answer, I'll award it. The data is structured well-enough. In any case, I inherited it and a refactor is outside the scope. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ng-if` directive removes the content from the page and `ng-show/ng-hide` uses the CSS display property to hide content.

So in your case as you are using the `ng-show` its just hiding the element not removing it from DOM. Just replace `ng-show/hide` with `ng-if`